# What is the solutions for reference error

Tags: mysql

Please help me, I am a new user of mysql. I found below error when I am trying to install Genus Leave managemnt system.

An error has occured. Report being generated now...

> Error:  This is the SQL error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column
>   'create_max_workspaces' at row 3

This is the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `core_role_master` 
values ('1','administrator','0','y','y','n','y','y','y','y'), 
       ('2','user','0','y','n','y','n','n','n','y'), 
       ('4','Basic','','y','n','n','n','n','n','n')
```

Report generated. Please go back and continue. The problem will be resolved soon.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. The table schema specifically.

Comment: Aren't you missing a value in the 3rd record 3rd paramter-  *('4','Basic',**''**,*?

Comment: u can try like: `('4','Basic',NULL,'y','n','n','n','n','n','n')` by using `NULL` or set column value NULL as default.